# disable auto windows update for windows server 2016 using powershell to change registry key

Tags: windows, powershell, registrykey, automatic-updates

I am trying to disable windows auto update by changing the registry key value for a VM. I have modified the 'NoAutoUpdate' key to 1 using below statement.

`set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU -Name NoAutoUpdates -Value 1`

But I see that after changing the registry value also some security patches were installed on the VM. 
So, Does changing registry key value requires a system reboot to take effect? if Yes, is there a way to avoid it, as it has to be done on production servers and we cant reboot them.

Comment: Better ask this question on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Have you checked through SCONFIG?

Comment: I have to do it for multiple server around 50, so i am building a custom script where remotely i will change the registry value of each server... i tried it for a VM and still the patches were installed. if we try with group policy or Sconfig these are the registry value which will be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You did:

```
set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU -Name NoAutoUpdates -Value 1`
```

It's supposed to be:

```
set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1
```

Omit the extra 's' in `NoAutoUpdates`.

Answer (score -1):

i turned off windows updates by configuring a fake WSUS server and disabling online lookups.

[[image: fake WSUS server1]]

Comment: okay. Does such changes in registry key requires a server reboot to take effect?

Comment: sorry i don't recall. maybe just give it a try and comment your results for future reference?

Comment: do you recall restarting windows update service after adding fake wsus server. According to a blog, reboot is required only for the operation which refer the registry key at boot time. But for updates, i am guessing registry key will be referred when update service is restarted. So, m guessing that restarting update service post changes in registry key should do the trick.

Comment: sorry i don't but restarting the wau service sounds like a good idea

Comment: changing AUOptions to 3 and NoAutoUpdate to 1 did the job.